# Problem passing selected options - POST method

Tags: php, html, jquery, select

I'm having problems with the passing of the selected options by the client (the select box is a multiple choice select box built with jquery). Basically, through the POST method, it's passing just the last option selected by the client, ignoring all the others.

```
 <form action="inserimento_fraseP.php" method="post">
    sigla Frase P <input type="text" name="siglaP" required/> <br />
    significato: <input type="text" name="significatoSiglaP" required/> <br />
    <br />
    sigla Frase H: <select class="mul-select" multiple="true" name="siglaH"> <?php select('siglaH', 'FraseH'); ?> </select>
    <input type="submit" value="inserisci"/>
</form>
<?php 
        function select($name, $tabella){
            include 'connessione_db.php';
            
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $name FROM $tabella ORDER BY $name";
            echo $sql;
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            echo "<option></option>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            { 
                echo "<option name='$row[$name]' value = '$row[$name]' > $row[$name] </option>";
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: `option` elements don't have a `name` attribute

Comment: I do have it since I print it through the while cycle in the select function.

Comment: try to use square brackets in the name of the select (like: <select name="yourname[]" ... )

Comment: `"I do have it since I print it through the while cycle in the select function"` - ? Just because you add the `name` attribute to the `option` does not mean that it is valid. Take a look at the [Global Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

Comment: I'd also suggest that including the database connection inside the `select` function is inefficient. If the page already has an active db connection you ought to pass the db connection as a parameter to the function

Comment: I found the problem. Instead of "siglaH" as name of the select I set "siglaH[]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE change the  name=siglaH[]

```
<select class="mul-select" name="siglaH[]" multiple="multiple">
---
</select>
```

you can check the by

```
print_r(implode(',', $_POST['siglaH']));
```

And ya one more thing I would like to tell you in your database store this field as varchar

Please set select name = siglaH[] then only you will get multiple data

Answer (score 0):

I edited the name of the select from "siglaH" to "siglaH[]" and in the .php file the action refers to I was able to handle the selected options as an array.